# Why were handcuffs ever made with a chain between them?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, solid-mechanics, mechanical, safety

I've noticed that modern handcuffs are always attached directly to each other, without any "chain" of any length in between. I guess I can understand why that make them safer and more robust.

But then why did they ever use that unnecessary chain in the first place? Why do extra work and cause extra cost for something that's pretty obviously a worse design? Am I missing something?

Comment: Because leg cuffs were made so convicts could walk and they were easily scaled down. Also some hand movement allows convicts to "take care" of themselves...

Comment: I'm not sure the chain is actually the weakest part. That might be the attachment on the cuff itself. Chains are real strong and the flexibility makes it more difficult to lever apart but also gives mobility to the prisoner. It might also be difficult to get in between the cuffs to weld the joint directly without chain (especially in medieval times where you need to hammer forge it).

Comment: I can certainly remember the introduction of rigid handcuffs in the UK in the 1990s being controversial, possibly because of an increased risk of injury to the prisoner associated with the ability of the link to support bending moments.